# Доступ к protected методам родителя

Tags: ооп, наследование, c++

Я столкнулся с проблемой в C++, для которой не могу найти нормального решения.
Проблему иллюстрирует следующий пример:

```
class Parent {
 protected:
  int f() = 0;
};

class Child : public Parent {
 protected:
  int g(Parent& p) {
    return p.f(); // error: 'virtual int Parent::f()' is protected.
  }
  int g(Child& p) {
    return p.f(); // OK.
  }
};
```

Я хочу, чтобы метод f() был доступен только наследникам класса Parent. В реальной задаче метод f() виртуальный и наследники его замещают (override), но сути проблемы это не меняет.

Я знаю 2 плохих решения:

- Сделать f() public. В данный момент его и использую. Этот решение плохое, потому что я не хочу давать доступ к f() кому-либо, кроме наследников.
- Добавить всех наследников в друзья родителя. Тут 2 минуса: private члены родителя становятся доступны наследникам, и при добавлении нового наследника, мы становимся обязаны обновить базовый класс.

Нашел [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829518/accessing-parents-protected-variables) на SO, но там никого нормального решения так и не нашлось.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как насчёт такого трюка: делегировать вызов `f` предку? ([Проверка.](http://ideone.com/WSTuN6))

```
class Parent {
 protected:
  virtual int f() = 0;
  int CallFOn(Parent& p) { return p.f(); }
};

class Child : public Parent {
 protected:
  int g(Parent& p) {
    return CallFOn(p); // OK.
  }
  int g(Child& p) {
    return p.f(); // OK.
    // или даже ( http://ideone.com/WLE27X )
    // return CallFOn(p);
  }
};
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то что надо.

Comment: @dzhioev: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Наверное легальным способом никак.

В качестве более удобного решения можно реализовать дружественный класс-обертку и обращаться к приватным/защищенным методам через него.

Думаю что плюсы очевидны: не нужно трогать базовый класс при добавлении дочерних, ну и можно менять реализацию в обертке не трогая дочерних классов, [dependency injection](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) и все такое :)